# VS2022 + ReSharper broken keyboard shortcut for navigate to Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, visual-studio-2022

I am using a fresh install of VS2022 (17.8.6) and ReSharper (2023.3.3). When editing a source file, the keyboard shortcut `Ctrl + [, S` does not behave as expected according to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#bkmk_solutionexplorerGLOBAL). It should select the file currently being edited in the Solution Explorer. On my machine, all the command does is type a single 's' character into the editor.

Looking in `Tools | Options... | Keyboard` the shortcut is correctly bound to command `SolutionExplorer.SyncWithActiveDocument`.

I have also seen this problem in multiple previous versions of VS and ReSharper.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is as follows, according to a [JetBrains issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-479375/Resharper-blocks-Visual-Studio-shortcut-SolutionExplorer.SyncWithActiveDocument). ReSharper installs a new keyboard shortcut for `Ctrl + [` which is bound to command `ReSharper.ReSharper_GotoContainingDeclaration`. This gets in the way of the two-part shortcut `Ctrl + [, S` so it is never executed.

Solution:

1. Go to `Tools | Options... | Keyboard`.
2. Search for 'ReSharper_GotoContainingDeclaration'.
3. Remove or replace its keyboard shortcut.